# disappearing mesh

Tags: mesh

I am very new to blender and went to making a simple sword but the tip of the blade disappears in object mode.
[image]

But in edit mode it is there. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I think it might have been bevelled away by the modifier.. set the modifier to be visible in Edit Mode ( the leftmost checkbox at the top of the mod., to have a look)